# how to write formula filter and how use it in SOQL

Tags: soql, formula-field, filters

Iam newbie to salesforce. Iam trying to write formula field for below filter:

```
Filtered By: not (1 or (2 AND 3 AND 4))
1. Price greater than "25,000"
2. SF greater than 20
3. PF Number not equal to 1
4. PF Number not equal to 100
```

How can i write SOQL query to get the above filtered records.

Iam getting stuck when writing formula/SOQL with this filter. Can any one help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Condition Expression Syntax (WHERE Clause)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm).

So (depending on the exact API names and data types of the fields) the `where` clause would be something close to:

```
select ...
from ...
where not (
    Price__c > 25000
    or
    (Sf__c > 20 and PfNumber__c != 1 and PfNumber != 100)
 )
```